# Javascript - Alternative to Slice

Tags: javascript

I want to shift the first letter of a word off and store it in a variable. Is there a way to do this in one statement?

Obviously this works, but it's longer than I'd like

```
new var = str.slice(0,1)
str = str.substr(1)
```

Comment: `[str.slice(0,2)[0]]`

Comment: What kind of syntax is `new var = `…?

Comment: You can't do this in 1 line, strings are immutable

Comment: Using comma expressions you can do all kinds of things in single statements, but that won't make the code better. You're a programmer, not a minifier, right?

Comment: May I ask why you want a shorter version? Unless you're doing this for code golf, what you already have is pretty short and tidy. (Though I'm not sure about the `new var =` bit)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a *reasonable* built-in way to do it, no. I'd stick with what you have, or at least something similar to it. It's short, it's clear, it's easy to debug.

The issue is that JavaScript strings are immutable, so we can't define any string method that would satisfy this usage requirement:

```
var first = str.getAndRemoveFirstCharacter();
```

...because it cannot modify the string. (There's one for arrays — `Array#shift` — but that's because arrays are mutable.) So we'd need to have a method that returned two different things (the first character, and the rest of the string). But functions can only have a single return value, and JavaScript doesn't have any form of pass-by-reference; so we'd have to make the function return a complex type (like an array)...

...at which point the "simplicity" ship has probably sailed. :-)

It's not necessarily *that* bad with ES2015's destructuring assignment. We could do this, for instance:

```
// ES2015+ only!
[first, str] = str.getAndRemoveFirstCharacter();
```

Like this:

```js
// ES2015+ only!

// In one central location, add a feature to string
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "getAndRemoveFirstCharacter", {
   value: function() {
     return [
       this[0],
       this.substring(1)
     ];
   }
});

// Using it:
let str, first;
str = "abcde";
[first, str] = str.getAndRemoveFirstCharacter();
console.log(`first: "${first}", str: "${str}"`);
```

---

In the ES5 and earlier world, you could do it with the comma operator:

```
first = str[0], str = str.substring(1);
```

```js
var str = "abcde";
var first;
first = str[0], str = str.substring(1);
console.log(first);
console.log(str);
```

...but that's just obscuring the fact you're really doing two things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way for such things with JavaString :

```
var str = "hello world";
var char ="";
var result = "";

str.split("").forEach((x, index) => { index===0 ? char = x : result += x});

console.log(result); // ello world
console.log(char);   // h
```

Answer (score -1):

There's not a standard function for this (mostly due to the fact that strings are immutable), but you could make your own function. E.g. (using ES6 destructuring):

```
function popChar(s) {
  return [ s.charAt(0), s.substring(1) ];
}

let str = "abc";
let a;
[a, str] = popChar(str);
```